# How to use user image input from a react app in python face recognition model?

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, image-processing, face-recognition

I have used the face-recognition library to compare two faces from given images but I want to take the images from a react app I built. I am taking both the images as user input from the react app. How do I use them in the model and then send both images to the database I created in atlas if they are of the same person.

This is the coding I am working on:

import face_recognition

known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("img1.jpeg")
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("img2.jpeg")

known_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]
unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

results = face_recognition.compare_faces([known_encoding], unknown_encoding)

Comment: Please provide a minimum example that works so the reader can understand what you want to do. (It's a requirement)

Comment: Added the code. Please refer to it.